# If $Z = X+iY$ is diagonalizable, are $X$ and $Y$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Converse of [If $X$ and $Y$ is diagonalizable, is $X+iY$ is diagonalizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527221/if-x-and-y-is-diagonalizable-is-xiy-is-diagonalizable?noredirect=1#comment5218849_2527221)

$Z \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

Write $Z = X+iY$, where $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Are $X$ and $Y$ diagonalizable?

Comment: If we take $Z$ in its diagonal form we have $Z \cdot e_i=z_{ii} e_i=(x_{ii}+iy_{ii})e_i=(X+iY)e_i=Xe_i+iYe_i$, so we should have $Xe_i=x_{ii}e_i$ and $Ye_i=y_{ii}e_i, \forall i$. So i think it is true.

Comment: @chak Let's call $\Re A$ and $\Im A$ the two real matrices such that $A=\Re A+i\Im A$, namely $\Re A=\frac{A+\overline A}2$ and $\Im A=\frac{A-\overline A}{2i}$. If $P\in GL(n,\Bbb C)$, in general $\Re(PAP^{-1})\ne P\Re (A)P^{-1}$ and $\Im(PAP^{-1})\ne P\Im(A)P^{-1}$. So, the fact that the claim holds in some basis tells you nothing about whether or not it happens for the actual $Z$, because, as it turns out, when the change of basis is not through a real matrix the real and imaginary parts may not even be similar.

Comment: Thank you. So because $P \in GL(n, \mathbb C)$ then we can't just take $X$ and $Y$ separated and transform them but we have to transform $Z$ and then obtain the two new matrices $X',Y'$, which in general are not just $X,Y$ with a change of basis. So i have showed that $X',Y'$ are diagonalizable, but not $X,Y$, am i right? Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $X=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $X+iY$ has two distinct eigenvalues, and it is thus diagonalizable.

**Added:** Or, if you don't like $Y$ diagonalizable, you can take $Y=X^t$. In that case, $\det(X+iY-\lambda I)=\lambda^2-i$ and the same argument applies.

Comment: Nice! A 2x2 example is surely better than a 3x3. Your $Y$ is diagonalizable, but that's probably not a problem for the OP :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yours was actually better, though, because neither $X$ nor $Y$ are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider
$$Z=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1+i&i&1\\
0&i&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right).
$$
$Z$ is diagonalizable because it is upper triangular with distinct diagonal elements.
OTOH
$$
X=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right)
$$
and
$$
iY=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
i&i&0\\
0&i&0\\
0&0&0
\end{array}\right)$$
both obviously have 2x2-blocks in their Jordan canonical form, and are not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a linear endomorphism $T$ is diagonalisable is basis-independent. However, the matrix (as well as its real part and imaginary parts) is obtained by choosing a basis first. While *some* matrix properties (such as matrix trace) that are defined in a basis-dependent manner turn out to be basis-independent, in general, it is hard to believe that some arbitrary matrix property will be basis-independent.

To illustrate, consider the example in G. Sassatelli's answer. Let $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ and $B=A^T$. Then $C=A+iB$ is diagonalisable but $A$ and $B$ are not. However, if you perform a change of basis via the matrix $P=\pmatrix{1&i\\ 0&1}$, you'll see that both the real and imaginary parts of $\widetilde{C}=P(A+iB)P^{-1}=\pmatrix{-1&1\\ 0&1}+i\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ are diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for adding this interesting point of view. I rather think of your example of saying that the real and imaginary parts of a matrix are not basis independent, but your point stands. +1

Comment: Yes, that clarified some things to me too. Thanks.